# Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish cannot install i3-gaps

Tags: repository, 22.04, i3-wm

I am running the latest release of ubuntu 22.04, I like I3 and wanted to start using I3-gaps instead. unfortunetly no matter which ppa I try to use it I get "404 not found" and  "jammy jellyfish does not have a release file" seems like its not supported. Is there any way I can still install i3-gaps?

Comment: games are not my nag but does [this guide](https://blog.benjames.io/2017/09/03/installing-i3-gaps-on-ubuntu-16-04/) help?

Comment: Use [official way of installing](https://github.com/Airblader/i3/wiki/installation) from github repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was running into the same problem as well. It looks like none of the PPA's listed on the Github are working anymore.

You can use this guide to build from source: https://gist.github.com/boreycutts/6417980039760d9d9dac0dd2148d4783

The only problem with this guide is that after installing the dependencies, installing i3-gaps using the installation tips fails on the line:

```
autoreconf --force --install
```

It seems that the current release of i3-gaps on github does not contain the "configure.ac" file necessary to run the command. To get around this, I built i3-gaps using github user Kabouik's suggestion in the thread:

```
mkdir /tmp/build 
cd /tmp/build
git clone https://www.github.com/Airblader/i3 i3-gaps
cd i3-gaps
git checkout gaps && git pull
sudo apt install meson asciidoc
meson -Ddocs=true -Dmans=true ../build
meson compile -C ../build
sudo meson install -C ../build
```

After this, the build succeeded, and you can log out and log back in, and configure the i3 config file with say:

```
gaps inner 5
gaps outer 5
```

To see the changes reflected after refreshing i3. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I made this post 7 months ago when I did not understand that much about linux. I am a lot more fluent now, thanks for your advice. I ran the the commands and I did not get any errors. However upon trying to run the commands gaps inner/outer 5 nothing happens, (literaly, the terminal curser justs hangs in limbo without ever finishing)

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no active PPA dedicated to **i3**. However, as the [**Regolith**](https://regolith-linux.org/) project continues to target Ubuntu as base system, you can get most of the goodies from their PPA. If you apply:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:regolith-linux/release`

**i3-gaps** should become available:

```
$ apt policy i3-gaps
i3-gaps:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.20-2-1regolith
  Version table:
     4.20-2-1regolith 500
        500 https://regolith-desktop.io/release-ubuntu-jammy-amd64 jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

As a side note, if you are into **i3** it might be worthy to give **Regolith** a try.

Answer (score 1):

Consider waiting a little while. [Gaps has been integrated into i3](https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/yjeoc9/psa_i3gaps_has_been_merged_into_i3/) and will be in the next version.

EDIT: I'm using it now (February 2023) and it works beautifully. [Installed from the PPA](https://i3wm.org/docs/repositories.html).

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer by Luis de Sousa, does not work =(

I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/regolith-linux/release/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I believe this to be the same error that the original poster gets.
I will attempt building from source instead.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1254431)

Answer (score -3):

You can add the regolit repo to your apt as described here:

https://regolith-desktop.com/